# Dynamic array declaration in java

Tags: java, arrays

can anyone tell me the error in this java declaration `String[][] t=new String[15][15];` this works fine and if i use `String[][] t=new String[][];` because i need to declare the variable t as dynamic as i am not sure how much values i am going to store in t.

Answer (score 8):

Use ArrayList (or other array object who can handle any number of objects). A java array always has a fixed length since some memory will be reserved for the array.

ArrayList creates such array as well to store the objects. Of you add more abjects as the current reserved size of the array than ArrayList will create a new bigger array (+50% if i'm correct). There are some other implementations that act a bit different (for example they create a new array 100% of the original one when the array is full. If performance is really important for you than you can look into this.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String> t = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>();

void fill() {
    ArrayList<String> t2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    t2.add("somestring");
    String s = "someotherstring";
    t2.add(s);
    t.add(t2);
}
```

Comment: A Java array always has a FIXED length, not a maximum. Some of the entries may be null.

Comment: While this is possible, you need to create an ArrayList of (ArrayList of String), and `s = t[3][12];` becomes `s = t.get(3).get(12);`

Comment: can i add multidimensional in array list???  i have a key and a value i store key in array [0][0] and values in [0][1] like that one key has many values...

Comment: If you have a key and a value you can use HashMap,`HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();`

Comment: If you're going to use the array for key/value pairs then Baijens answer above would work best imo.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know how big it needs to be just declare it as

```
String[][] t;
```

and once you know how big it needs to be you can do (**before** trying to use the array)

```
t = new String[15][15];
```

If you're never sure how big the array need to be, you'll need to use something like a List of Lists.

```
List<List<String>> t = new ArrayList<List<String>>;

public void add(String str, int row, int col) {
    while (row >= t.size())
        t.add(new ArrayList<String>());

    List<String> row_list = t.get(row);
    while (col >= row_list.size())
        row_list.add("");

    row_list.set(col, str);
}
```

Comment: if i use `String[][] t= null; ` i am getting an error that Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException while using it `t[0][0]="ana"`

Comment: @raju : you still need to do `t = new String[sizeX][sizeY];` *after* you've discovered what the dimensions need to be but *before* your `t[0][0] =` assignment.

Answer (score 1):

In Java array objects are always of fixed length. Once you have allocated them you cannot change their size. An array **variable** can be made to point to different array objects of different size. So you can allocate:

```
String[][] t;
```

which doesn't point to an object and allocate an object later once you know the size:

```
int n1,n2;
// calculate n1,n2
t = new String[n1][n2];
```

If you need a structure where the size can change you are much better off using ArrayList, which can be dynamically resized.

Answer (score 1):

Declare it as `String [][]t = null;`

And **Reinitialize** it with ***actual length*** once you get it.

```
t=new String[x][y];
```

Comment: best way to real use case.

Answer (score 0):

As bemace said, just because you are declaring the variable doesn't mean you have to initialize it immediately.

As Mark said, arrays have a fixed size.  Once an array is *initialized*(not declared, initialized) it has a fixed size.

So, there are two possibilities:

Either you will know how big the array needs to be before you need to start using it, in which case you can simply delay your initialization as suggested by bemace.

Or you won't know how big it needs to be before you start using it, in which case you need to use a dynamically sized data structure(s).  Check out the Java Collections API:

[tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)
[api reference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are several good answers already, but it has now been revealed in a comment to [Mark Baijens' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054255#4054274) that the purpose of this question is that raju need a *key to multi-value* mapping.

Mark followed up that comment by suggesting raju use a `HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();` — however that only works for a single key-value pair.

What raju needs is a

```
Map<String, Collection<String>> t
    = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Adding the first value for a key requires initialization of a List for that bucket, while adding additional values requires fetching the existing list and adding the new value.

Note I used `Collection<String>` in the declaration, so it could be a List if the order of values is important, or it could be a Set to prevent duplicate values under the same key.

This would probably be best implemented as a Class itself, perhaps

```
public class MultiValueMap<K, V> extends Map<K, V>
{
    ...
}
```

so the initialization of the List on the first `put(key, value)` and the subsequent `.add(value)` to the list could be hidden in the implementation.